# Error 'failed to create directory locally' while downloading with Fire FTP

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-netbook, ftp, firefox-extensions

I'm using Fire FTP (Firefox add-on) in Ubuntu to download my project locally but when I click on download, it says `failed to create directory "Project1" locally`. Is there any root permission issue? if yes then how I can download my project using Fire FTP?

Comment: Are you using apparmor?

Comment: apparmor? i am using fireftp, it is an add on for fire fox

Comment: I know that you`re using fireftp, apparmor is a security module for the Linux kernel.  Do you have it installed?

Comment: ahh sorry, while typing 'apparmor_status' gives me apparmor module is loaded. i think it is installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparmor is stopping fireftp traffic, so you need to configure apparmor to allow FireFTP.  If more help is needed in regards to apparomr [have a look at this site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor)

Comment: I have stopped apparmor but it is still saying the same 'failed to create directory locally' :(

Comment: What version fireftp are you running?

Comment: its fireftp 2.0.4

Comment: What mode are you using under the Connection Tab?

Comment: it is passive mode checked

Comment: same problem with the filezilla. in fact i am copying downloading it to /opt/lampp/htdocs.
it is also saying failed to create directory :(

Comment: How are you copying?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3661/discussion-between-mitch-and-baig772)

Comment: just downloading it

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is some root permission issue. Now downloaded my project to Downloads and moved it to /opt/lampp/htdocs. Now it is working fine

Comment: I`m glad it worked out :)

Comment: yup but using alternative way :)